How to play audio in the background when triggered but still run code
So the code sends an audio alert everytime something fulfills the if statement. However, the code will pause for about 3s (the audio file length) and will pause the While loop, making the OpenCV video stop.  Btw I am deploying this to Flask. Here's the code:
while True:
            ret, frame = self.video.read()
            results = self.model.track(frame)
            frame_result = results[0].plot()

            for r in results:
        
                boxes = r.boxes
                for box in boxes:
            
                    c = box.cls
                    if model.names[int(c)] == 'cell phone':
                        playsound('audio.mp3') #i want this to play in background while code is still runninng
            ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame_result)
            frame = jpeg.tobytes()
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')

I was surfing through and saw threading and asyncio? Alas, I am still unfamiliar with how to implement them in this scenario.

It's possible to run audio in the background without stopping the main loop, you can use threading with the following conditions
import threading
from playsound import playsound
import cv2

def play_audio():
playsound('audio.mp3')

  while True:
   ret, frame = self.video.read()
   results = self.model.track(frame)
   frame_result = results[0].plot()

  for r in results:
    boxes = r.boxes
    for box in boxes:
        c = box.cls
        if model.names[int(c)] == 'cell phone':
            audio_thread = threading.Thread(target=play_audio)
            audio_thread.start()
            
  ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame_result)
  frame = jpeg.tobytes()
  yield (b'--frame\r\n'
         b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')'

According to me by using threading, the play_audio function will run in a separate thread, so the main loop will not stop while audio is playing.

Thank you, it works! However, the audio plays continuously, overlapping each other. Do you have an idea on how to fix that? Many thanks again :)

You should fix your indentation, preferably to 4 spaces per level.

First add a flag audio playinng,
   `self.audio_playing = False`

Modification this Function
   `def play_audio(self):  
      playsound('audio.mp3')  self.audio_playing = False`

last add a condition in loop;
  `if self.model.names[int(c)] == 'cell phone' 
           and not self.audio_playing:     self.audio_playing = True     
           audio_thread =  threading.Thread(target=self.play_audio)    
                   audio_thread.start()`


Edit your answer!

I've just started and don't quite understand what you mean @KlausD.

Do not post code in the comment. Edit your answer instead.
